# Angular2 Material2 how way to style elements

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am curious as to why some of my scss does not correctly work with the angular-material2 elements.  I am using node-sass to compile my scss and it does not seem to be correctly affecting the css files.  For example I am using the material2 demo app which has this:

```
.demo-sidenav-layout {
   md-sidenav {
        background-color: $left_nav;
        padding: 10px;
   }
}
```

(I added the background color).  Is this the correct way to style the elements or should I just use classes.  When I added just a class with my desired background-color it was overwritten by the default element style.

Comment: I have an answer on a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39379754/13825

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying style to Material2 component does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360065/applying-style-to-material2-component-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material2 use a theme base for elements in the core. You can modificated the style using mixins with Sass or defined a theme specific for your App. The way for use this, is:

First, create a theme using the official documentation:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Second, create a mixin for a component selected:

The way for completed this, is easy. You must created a new components, for example

```
ng g c components/my_component_styleded
```

this create 4 files:

- my_component_styleded.component.html
- my_component_styleded.component.html.scss
- my_component_styleded.component.spec.ts
- my_component_styleded.component.html.ts

In the *.scss include the general style for your component (structure style) and in the *.html file include the structure HTML for yout component.
For example:

```
<div>
 <button md-raised-button routerLink="/stock">STOCK OF PRODUCTS</button>
</div>
```

Now, created a new file called: 'my_component_styleded.component.html.scss-theme.scss' in the directory, and with the follow code use the mixin for personalize the button element:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@mixin my_component_styleded-theme($theme) {
    $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
    $accent: map-get($theme, accent);

    div {
    button {
        color: $accent;
        &:hover, &:focus {
            color: $primary;
            border-left: 5px solid mat-color($accent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can declare other variables with Sass and other thing in your mind.

Finally, you must add this mixin in the main style.scss of the App:

-- style.scss --

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// Custom component themes:
@import 'app/components/my_component_styleded/my_component_styleded.component.scss-theme';
@mixin custom_component-theme($asis-light-theme) {
    @include my_component_styleded-theme($asis-light-theme);
}

// Light Theme
@include angular-material-theme($asis-light-theme);
@include custom-component-theme($asis-light-theme);
```

;)