# Applying style to Material2 component does not work

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have an `<md-input>` element:

```
<md-input class="filter-name-input" [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Name"></md-input>
```

And am trying to apply styling to it via a CSS:

```
md-input {
    height: 2000000px;
}
```

I'm not seeing the style being applied in the browser debugger. Am I doing this improperly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are doing right have a look at this plunker

<kbd>[working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/taB1pVyBRxg1zOlKKyeI?p=preview)</kbd>

```
<md-input #startDate
          required
          name="startDate"
          placeholder="startDate">
</md-input>
</p> 

<style>
  md-input{height:1000px; background:red;}
</style>
```

actually css height is being applied to your component but may not be visible due to white background, see in the attached plunker its working fine for me.

Comment: My style class is in a separate .css file. Does that affect things? What i'm trying to do specifically is, add background-color to the `<input>` of `<md-input>`

Comment: No I doesn't affect at all whether it's a separate file or internal CSS I think. I haven't tried it yet but m pretty sure about that

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You can use a link tag in your index.html to override the component styles, a la:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-global-styles.css">`

Link styles are not overridden by component styles.

**Long Answer**

This is due to Angular 2's *ViewEncapsulation*, which isolates styles for reusable components. It prevents the styles from the individual component from leaking out and affecting other components in your app, but it also prevents you from reaching in to style a component, if it has not been explicitly allowed by the component implementer.

The following articles might be of some help:

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html
- https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-2-components
- https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation